# Filter dataframe rows based on multiple column values that can contain one or more null values in Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a json in this format

```
{
    "userobject": ["Nike", "NY", "", "Actor", "Artist"]
}
```

I have a dataframe where all the columns have values except the `Country` column which is empty and is denoted by`""` in the json above.

I want to fetch all rows from the dataframe that has similar values from the json. My code:

```
org = userobject[0]
region = userobject[1]
country = userobject[2]
title = userobject[3]
dept = userobject[4]
newdf = df[(df['Organization'] == org) & (df['Region'] == region) & (df['Country']== country)) & (df['Title'] == title) & (df['Department'] == dept)]
```

But this breaks my code and it only works if i remove this `(df['Country']== country))` part. But I need to also use this clause as my dataframe should be filtered dynamically from the json and for some dataframes, Country value will be there. Can someone please help me with this

Update:
The suggested code fails for this condition. The dataframe is:

```
    User    Organization    Region  Country Title   Department  Output
0   rp990.john1001@gmail.com    ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
1   rp1007.john1007@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
2   rp1012.john1012@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
3   rp1001.john1001@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
4   rp1017.john1017@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
5   rp1006.john1006@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
6   rp1011.john1011@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
7   rp1016.john1016@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
8   rp1005.john1005@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
9   rp1010.john1010@gmail.com                                  -1
10  rp1015.john1015@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
11  rp1004.john1004@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
12  rp1020.john1020@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
13  rp1009.john1009@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
14  rp1014.john1014@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
15  rp1003.john1003@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
16  rp1019.john1019@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
17  rp1008.john1008@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
18  rp1013.john1013@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
19  rp1002.john1002@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
20  rp1018.john1018@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
21  rp1027.john1027@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
22  rp1021.john1021@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
23  rp1026.john1026@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
24  rp1025.john1025@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
25  rp1024.john1024@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
26  rp1029.john1029@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
27  rp1023.john1023@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
28  rp1028.john1028@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
29  rp1022.john1022@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
30  rp1036.john1036@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
31  rp1052.john1052@gmail.com                                  -1
32  rp1041.john1041@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
33  rp1057.john1057@gmail.com                                  -1
34  rp1030.john1030@gmail.com   ABC.com BR      DEV Engineering -1
35  rp1046.john1046@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV MCA        -1
36  rp1035.john1035@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
37  rp1051.john1051@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
38  rp1040.john1040@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV MCA        -1
39  rp1056.john1056@gmail.com                                  -1
40  rp1045.john1045@gmail.com   ABC.com BR      DEV Engineering -1
41  rp1034.john1034@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV MAC         -1
42  rp1050.john1050@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
43  rp1039.john1039@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
44  rp1055.john1055@gmail.com                                  -1
45  rp1044.john1044@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
46  rp1060.john1060@gmail.com                                  -1
47  rp1033.john1033@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
48  rp1049.john1049@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
49  rp1038.john1038@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering  1
50  rp1054.john1054@gmail.com                                   -1
51  rp1043.john1043@gmail.com   ABC.com KRI IN  DEV Engineering -1
52  rp1059.john1059@gmail.com                                   -1
53  rp1032.john1032@gmail.com   ABC.com KRI IN  DEV Engineering -1
54  rp1048.john1048@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
55  rp1037.john1037@gmail.com   ABC.com     PH  DEV Engineering -1
56  rp1053.john1053@gmail.com                                   -1
57  rp1042.john1042@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
58  rp1058.john1058@gmail.com                                   -1
59  rp1031.john1031@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
60  rp1047.john1047@gmail.com   ABC.com BR  IN  DEV Engineering 1
```

and condition for filter is :

["ABC.com", "BR", "", "DEV", "Engineering"] of user rp1045.john1045@gmail.com

Comment: Regarding the dataframe: What exactly is in the places where there is nothing shown, e.g. line 9, column Organization: Is it `""` or `NaN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) to build the condition dynamically:

```
from functools import reduce

cols = ['Organization', 'Region', 'Country', 'Title', 'Department']
json_dict = {"userobject": ["Nike", "NY", "", "Actor", "Artist"]}

cond = reduce(
    lambda r, p: r & (df[p[0]] == p[1]),
    ((c, v) for c, v in zip(cols, json_dict["userobject"]) if v != ""),
    pd.Series(True, index=df.index)
)
newdf = df[cond]
```

`reduce` will start out with the initial value as `r`: The last argument, here a series that is filled with `True` (`pd.Series(True, index=df.index)`). Then it will successively "reduce" the given iterable, the second argument, via the function given as the first argument. The pairs in the iterable are (column name, corresponding value from userobject) (`(c, v)`) filtered by the value: if the value is `""` it is filtered out. The `lambda` function takes the already build condition `r` and adds `& (df[c] == v)` to it.

---

If you don't like this solution, here's an adaption of @ShubhamSharma approach:

```
cols = ['Organization', 'Region', 'Country', 'Title', 'Department']
json_dict = {"userobject": ["ABC.com", "BR", "", "DEV", "Engineering"]}

col_val = [(c, v) for c, v in zip(cols, json_dict["userobject"]) if v != ""]
if col_val:
    cols_used, values = map(list, zip(*col_val))
else:
    cols_used, values = [], []
newdf = df[df[cols_used].eq(values).all(1)]
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but I can't understand the logic. Can you please tell me. And will this code work if there is no null value in the json_dict?

Comment: @Swordsman I've added some explanations. I hope they are helpful. I don't see a reason why no null value in json_dict shouldn't work.

Comment: It's not working for all scenarios

Comment: @Swordsman How does a scenario look like for which it isn't working?

Comment: I have added the scenarios in the question, can you please check. Also, it's failing when the entire input is Null

Comment: @Swordsman What exactly does `Null` mean: `""` or `None`, ...?

Comment: Null means when we are passing "". I have added it in the example : ["ABC.com", "BR", "", "DEV", "Engineering"]

Comment: @Swordsman With the missing values in `df` as `""` this works for me? What do mean when you say _failing_? It would be helpful if you could be more specific about the expected output.

Comment: I have just added this line `df = df.replace(np.nan, 'null_value', regex=True)` and I think it should work. But I really cannot understand the reduce logic. Let me go through the documentation

Answer (score -1):

You have to first fill the `null` values with empty strings before creating the mask..further you can simplify your code by using `eq` to compare the columns with `userobject` list followed by `all` for reduction of boolean mask along the columns axis:

```
cols = ['Organization', 'Region', 'Country', 'Title', 'Department']
df[df[cols].fillna('').eq(userobject).all(1)]
```

Comment: I added these lines to my code but still getting the same error. Can you please suggest the changes to my code.